# include_path doesn't recurse?

Tags: php, server-side-includes, include-path

I have several separate websites that live in separate directories. For includes that they have in common, I have it living in the root directory where the rest of them live.

```
user@hostname:/var/www$ ls
website_1 website_2 website_3 common_files
```

I want to include a Zend package, so I have my include path

```
ini_set("include_path", get_include_path() . ":/var/www/common_files/Zend");
require_once("Mail.php");
```

`Mail.php` loads okay, but then somewhere in there is this line

```
require_once 'Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php';
```

which gives this error

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in var/www/common_files/Zend/Mail.php on line 26
```

So php doesn't recursively descend into the directory structure of the include paths. Do I have to move Zend into each website direcory, spell out the path to every include, or what?

---

BTW Abstract does exist:

```
user@host:/var/www/common_files/Zend$ tree -d 
...
`-- Mail/Transport
    |-- Mail/Transport/Abstract.php
    |-- Mail/Transport/Exception.php
    |-- Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php
    `-- Mail/Transport/Smtp.php

9 directories, 32 files
```

Comment: Try using the constant `PATH_SEPARATOR` instead of the colon...  so `get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/var/www/common_viles/Zend');`

Comment: This has bugged me too many times. When you include a file, it is run from the same path is the including file is. Unless they are in the same folder, any relative paths in the included file will cause errors.

Does anyone know of a solution to this?

Comment: @Adrian, I think it is common practice to use dirname for this.  `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/relative/path/../here';`

Comment: I guess the solution is that library files shouldn't have hard-coded includes in them :P

Comment: @Brandon Ah, yes, that would make the path look absolute when compiled, right? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: You want to change your include_path to include `/var/www/common_files`

What, if anything, is still broken after you do this?

Comment: Where do I include it the second time? The `require_once` line you reference is in Zend's Mail.php library file, not in my file. They intended it to work this way.

Comment: If the require_once is outside of your control, then try changing the ini_path to just `/var/www/common_files` and alter your `Mail.php` to be `Zend/Mail.php`

Comment: Exactly.  ZF expects the top-level Zend/ directory to be inside a directory in the include_path.  OP wants `/var/www/common_files` in his include path.

Answer (score 1):

Stupid answer: Does Abstract.php exist?

```
require_once 'Mail/Transport/Abstract.php';
```

Try this, because Mail.php iz already in Zend folder, I guess it looks for /Zend/Zend/.../Abstract.php

Comment: I would include that, but there are other includes, so is there a way around writing an include for each file? Why can't the `require_once` that the Zend folks wrote into their files just work?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `Zend`is the working directory here, so your statement is looking for `/Zend/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php`. Try just cutting off `Zend` from the statement and it should work fine.

Comment: IT works, but I don't get it. If the include_path is just `/var/www/common_files` and I `require_once('Mail.php')`, how does it know to put the `Zend` in the middle? The path to `Mail.php` is `/var/www/common_files/Zend/Mail.php`

Comment: Oh, I get it. It *does* recursively search the directory! :P

Comment: If Mail.php exists in the same directory as the php file including it, and `.` is in the include_path, then it will be found without searching through the rest of your include_path.

Comment: It doesn't exist in the same directory. It exists one dir above, in a common directory, so I don't have to include it redundantly in five different projects.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set your include path to the path where the Zend folder is. then you include the files like so

```
require_once 'Zend/Mail.php'
```